# Correcting my Date Output from SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date

I am having a problem: Trying to use SimpleDateFormat with user input...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY",Locale.US);
sdf.setLenient(false);
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      String myDate;
out.print("Please enter today's date [MM/DD/YYYY]: ");
myDate = myScanner.next();
Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
out.println("Today is : " + date);
} catch (ParseException e) {    e.printStackTrace();    }
}
```

The result is this:

```
Please enter today's date [MM/DD/YYYY]: 09/21/2008
Today is : Sun Dec 30 00:00:00 EST 2007
```

Comment: ALSO, I want  "Today is : 09/21/2008" without the "00:00:00 EST" and "SUN DEC" crap... Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should use small y - MM/dd/yyyy.

This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) should be your friend when dealing with date format problems.

Comment: A [link to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) would make this answer even better.

Comment: btw: most IDEs have context help... I just had to press CTRL+SPACE in Netbeans and there it was...

Comment: ALSO, I want "Today is : 09/21/2008" without the "00:00:00 EST" and "SUN DEC" crap... Thanks.

Comment: @user2151918 then don't print out the date object (out.println("Today is : " + date); internally invokes toString on you Date object); instead use System.out.println("Today is : " + sdf.format(date));

Comment: THANK YOU ALL FOR THE HELP. WORKS GREAT!

Comment: @user2151918 in which  case you should upvote and accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY",Locale.US);` must be `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy",Locale.US);`

- `YYYY` = Week year
- `yyyy` = Year