# Java Joda-Time , assign LocalDate to Month and Year

Tags: java, jodatime

I have never used [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) before but I have ArrayList which contains objects with LocalDate and count. So I have count for each day in ArrayList and each day is only once in ArrayList.
I need to calculate counts for each month of year, which is in list.

My data:
E.g.:

```
dd.MM.yyyy
17.01.1996 (count 2)
18.01.1996 (count 3)
19.02.1996 (count 4)
19.03.1996 (count 1)
18.05.1997 (count 3)
```

Now I want outpur like this:

```
MM.yyyy
01.1996 -> 2 (17.1.1996) +  3 (18.1.1996) = 5
02.1996 -> 4 (19.2.1996)                  = 4
03.1996 -> 1 (19.3.1996)                  = 1
05.1997 -> 3 (18.5.1997)                  = 3
```

Simply I need to get count for each month, but I do not know what would be best way to achieve this.

Data class:

```
private class Info{
   int count;
   LocalDate day;
}
```

And result I would put in some class which contains Month and Year date + count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15313090/642706), there is class that represents Year + Month information, named [`YearMonth`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/YearMonth.html).

What you need to do is mostly construct a `Map<YearMonth, int>` to store the count of each `YearMonth`, by looping through your original `List` which contains [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) and count, and update the map accordingly.

Conversion from `LocalDate` to `YearMonth` should be straight forward: `YearMonth yearMonth = new YearMonth(someLocalDate);` should work

in pseudo-code, it looks like:

```
List<Info> dateCounts = ...;
Map<YearMonth, Integer> monthCounts = new TreeMap<>();

for (Info info : dateCounts) {
    YearMonth yearMonth = new YearMonth(info.getLocalDate());
    if (monthCounts does not contains yearMonth) {
        monthCounts.put(yearMonth, info.count);
    } else {
        oldCount = monthCounts.get(yearMonth);
        monthCounts.put(yearMonth, info.count + oldCount);
    }
}

// feel free to output content of monthCounts now.
// And, with TreeMap, the content of monthCounts are sorted
```

Comment: Thanks ,its working like it should. You just made small mistake in psuedocode new YearCount(info.getLocalDate()); should be new YearMonth (info.getLocalDate()); ,but its easy to figure it out.

Comment: @user3658759 lol I don't know why I wrote that weird class name there.  Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`getMonthOfYear`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#getMonthOfYear%28%29) and [`getYear`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#getYear%28%29) methods on the [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
for ( Info info : infos ) {
    int year = info.day.getYear();
    int month = info.day.getMonthOfYear();
}
```

From there, write code to roll-up the count in any way that suits you. You could keep a map of years as keys leading to a map of months. You could create a string in the format of "YYYY-MM" as a key to map.