# How to format a localized date without specifying a localized pattern?

Tags: java, date, datetime, formatting, simpledateformat

I have this pattern `MMMM YYYY`, but my locale is `es_MX` so I get the infamous `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'` exception.

The problem is that I get the exception right at the constructor:

```
new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale);
```

So I can't create a new instance with just the `Locale` (so then I could apply a locale-less pattern with `applyPattern`) nor apply a `Locale` after instatiation so I could then call `toLocalizedPattern()` so that it returns the localized version of `MMMM YYYY`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correcting my Date Output from SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313090/correcting-my-date-output-from-simpledateformat)

Comment: It is indeed, I just couldn't find any reference to that question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for year - pattern is `yyyy` not `YYYY`

> is that so? I had this code working a few months ago and the case was never a problem. –

[java 7 onwards supports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `Y` and it represents week year - so this code likely to work without exception (not as expected though)

[java 6 or prior doesn't support `Y`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) so it will fail to parse

Comment: Is that so? I had this code working a few months ago and the case was never a problem.

Comment: You probably had a small bug which kicked in at the beginnings and ends of the years, when the calendar year and the week year didn't line up.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, however as I asked in a comment above I don't get why it's a illegal character if the doc says it's valid.

Comment: `java 6 doesn't support Y so it will fail to parse` I'll have to check against what API I'm compiling my project (it's an Android project), maybe it's using the Java 6 API.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `yyyy` lower case is for Year.

And `YYYY` upper case is for Week Year.

See API doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: And what is the problem with `YYYY`? I don't get why if the doc specifies it, it's still an illegal symbol

Comment: It's illegal in Java 6 and below only.

Comment: I did, thank you, I have to check with what API my project is being compiled.